# hyperledger fabric - problem with crytogen tool

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I want to create a hyperledger fabric network and create my crypto-config.yaml. but in next step according to document  I run this commans :

```
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD
mkdir channel-artifacts
configtxgen -profile ThreeOrgsOrdererGenesis -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block
```

but I got this message :

> 2020-01-22 14:33:12.289 +0330 [common/tools/configtxgen] main -> WARN
>   001 Omitting the channel ID for configtxgen is deprecated.  Explicitly
>   passing the channel ID will be required in the future, defaulting to
>   'testchainid'. 2020-01-22 14:33:12.289 +0330
>   [common/tools/configtxgen] main -> INFO 002 Loading configuration
>   2020-01-22 14:33:12.290 +0330 [common/tools/configtxgen/localconfig]
>   LoadTopLevel -> CRIT 003 Error reading configuration:  Unsupported
>   Config Type "" 2020-01-22 14:33:12.290 +0330
>   [common/tools/configtxgen] func1 -> ERRO 004 Could not find
>   configtx.yaml. Please make sure that FABRIC_CFG_PATH or --configPath
>   is set to a path which contains configtx.yaml

where is my mistake? what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The configtx.yaml file is missing,as stated in the error.The path is unspecified.

You should try the command from the directory where this configtx.yaml is located.

Answer (score 0):

The first warning is correct but you can avoid it.

Let's focus on

```
ERRO 004 Could not find configtx.yaml. Please make sure that FABRIC_CFG_PATH or --configPath is set to a path which contains configtx.yaml
```

The message is clear: you are missing configtx.yaml.
Do you have this file in your Fabric folder? This is mandatory to generate crypto materials.

Comment: yes I have, I check it multiple time, is there a necessary location for that?

Comment: Place it in the same directory of the script you are using :)

Answer (score 0):

run the below command:

export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=

After the above command, you can try the using cryptogen